# Invalid URI: Host could not be parsed

Tags: c#, hosting, .net-5

I know this is an common issue, however, I've tried many solutions but still can't get it to work. I haven't changed anything in the project. Just left it for a while wile working on other things. Maybe a week or two.

### When it Happens

When I run the project in both release and debug from visual studio.

### What I've tried

- Deleted \Documents\IISExpress\Config
- Delete .vs
- Updateding Visual Studio
- Repairing Visual Studio
- Changing Luanch Settings Port

### lauchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50235",
      "sslPort": 44351
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Marel.Lairage.Blazor": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "applicationUrl": "http://*:900",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Project

.NET 5

Is there any other definition I can add to help solve this issue?

Comment: Do you know *which* `URI` could not be parsed? I'm assuming that, since you posted the `lauchSettings.json`, it has to do with this file, is that correct? Could it be the `"applicationUrl": "http://*:900"`?

Comment: @Aage, I'm not sure. I was able to run the settings with this URI before, so don't know why it would not work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change `applicationUrl` from `"http://*:900",` to `"http://localhost:900",`
2. Make sure that the [URLS for ASPNET.CORE](https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/) is **not** `...*:PORT`